# When using application cache manifest, where does data load first from?

Tags: caching, mobile-safari, cache-manifest

I'm creating a web application for mobile devices which uses Application cache.

When I open it using Safari for iPhone, the updated changes are reflected.
Now I add it to home screen and then open it from the homescreen. This time the changes are not reflected. I'm guessing it is loading from the old application cache.
Why is the two different?

I then changed the manifest file so that the new files will swap the old cache. But still the changes are not reflected.

Again my questions are

1. If I've cache files and I'm also online, where does the files load from first: from
   the cache or from online?
2. How do I make sure that the files are
   loaded from online if I'm online and not from the offline cached
   files. I want the offline files to be loaded only if I'm offline.

Answer (score 1):

1. Files getting always loaded from cache if they're in.
2. As far as I worked out that's not possible. Tell me please if you found a solution.